# Running a class as a JApplet or a JFrame?

Tags: java

If I want to make a class that can be run as both an JApplet and JFrame I thought that all the class had to do was extend the JApplet. I had asked this question in a post earlier but I am not sure how to extends this question to that question. I have the life cycle of an applet included in this code and along with the main method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LifeCycle extends Applet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    String output = "test";
    String event;

    public void init()
    {
                gui(); //I am not certain if this needs to be there. 
        event = "\nInitializing...";
        printOutput();
    }

    public void start()
    {
        event = "\nStarting..."; 
        printOutput();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        event = "\nStopping...";
        printOutput();
    }

    public void destroy()
    {
        event = "\nDestroying...";
        printOutput();
    }

    private void printOutput()
    {
        System.out.println(event);
        output += event;
        repaint();
    }

    private void gui() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Not resizable");
        JPanel d = new JPanel();
        d.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        f.add(d);
        f.setSize(745,440); 
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setTitle("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("Graphics Paint Method!");
        g.drawString(output, 100, 100);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LifeCycle l = new LifeCycle();
        l.gui();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need something that can be run in a `JFrame` or a `JApplet`, put all the logic and things into a `JPanel` and depending on which you want make either a `JFrame` or a `JApplet` and add the `JPanel` to either.

Edit for all those lifecycle things, you can have either the applet or frame call them as necessary on your panel.

Edit: example

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public MyPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    String output = "test";
    String event;

    public void init()
    {
        event = "\nInitializing...";
        printOutput();
    }
    // Put all the other methods in here too

    private void printOutput()
    {
        System.out.println(event);
        output += event;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.out.println("Graphics Paint Method!");
        g.setColor(this.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.setColor(this.getForeground());
        g.drawString(output, 100, 100);
    }
}
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    MyPanel myPanel;
    public MyFrame()
    {
        super("Test frame");
        setSize(745,440); 
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        myPanel=new MyPanel();
        add(myPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class MyApplet extends JApplet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    MyPanel myPanel;

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        myPanel = new MyPanel();
        getContentPane().add(myPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

Then add methods to `JFrame` and `JApplet` to call the relevant methods on `myPanel`

For `JFrame` I recommend `WindowListener` and whatnot. For `JApplet` you can just have the init, start, destroy and stop methods to call those methods on the panel.

For `WindowListener` or perhaps more conveniently `WindowAdapter`, this link seems to be a good reference: http://way2java.com/awt-components/java-frame-closing-windowadapter/

Answer (score 1):

Simply `add()` the applet to a `JFrame` and then call the applet's life cycle methods on the appropriate events (`init()` after you construct it, `destroy()` when the frame is closing etc)

Edit: yes the call to `gui()` should be there and not in main

Comment: private void gui() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Not resizable");
        JPanel d = new JPanel();
        d.add(new LifeCycle());
        d.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        f.add(d);
        f.setSize(745,440); 
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setTitle("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } Where does the init() go. I create a Frame and a Panel. I create and new LifeCycle applet in the panel and add that to the Jframe. It will run as an applet but not as a frame and will not let me choose applet or applic

Comment: you don't need the `JPanel`, you can add to the frame directly. after you call the constructor, you should call `init()`